# ReactHtmlParser is not binding in textarea value property

Tags: html, reactjs

I have used ReactHtmlParser for binding content with HTML tag. When I bind this at `textarea` it shows `[object][object]`.

But when I set this at HTML `label` tag it is working fine.
Why is this happening?

```
<textarea
  className="form-control"
  aria-label="With textarea"
  placeholder="Remark"
  name="Remarks"
  value={ReactHtmlParser(this.state.Remarks)}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
></textarea>
```

Comment: refer this link, https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#why-textarea-value

Comment: You need to check first you will get proper HTMl in value, when you did not get value proper that time this type of issue will occur

Answer (score 0):

Simple! ReactHtmlParser() returns an HTML element object, and textarea expects plain text as its value. I'm guessing you are trying to build an HTML editor. Then you have to use it as below:

```
<textarea
  className="form-control"
  aria-label="With textarea"
  placeholder="Remark"
  name="Remarks"
  value={this.state.Remarks}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
></textarea>
```

and the handle change:

```
handleChange = (event)=>{
    this.setState({
        Remarks: event.target.value
    })
}
```

then at preview/view :

```
<div> { ReactHtmlParser(this.state.Remarks) } </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Textarea` is showing the value [object Object] correctly.

`ReactHtmlParser(this.state.Remarks)` returns object which when converted to string gives us `[object Object]`.

The correct use would be to put html inside the `textarea` and render it elsewhere.

Working code here:-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Remarks: `<div>Hi, 
    <button>My Button</button>
  </div>`
  };
  handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <textarea
          className="form-control"
          aria-label="With textarea"
          placeholder="Remark"
          name="Remarks"
          value={this.state.Remarks}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        {ReactHtmlParser(this.state.Remarks)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```